# Se edita solo el primer elemento en un accordion

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando realizar un accordion (Faq's) para mi sitio web en un apartado de preguntas frecuentes. Al hacer click en un elemento se edita el símbolo *fa-plus* únicamente en el primer `div` *faq-options*: no entiendo por qué sucede y necesito que se edite solamente en el que estoy clickeando.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="faq-accordion">
        
        <div class="faq-options">
            <button class="accordion">pregunta 1<i class="fas fa-plus" id="plus"></i></button>
            <div class="panel">
              <p>prueba</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="faq-options">
            <button class="accordion">pregunta 2 <i class="fas fa-plus" id="plus"></i></button>
            <div class="panel">
              <p>prueba</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");

          
          var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
          if (plus.classList.contains("fa-plus")){
          plus.classList.replace("fa-plus", "fa-minus");
            } else{
          plus.classList.replace("fa-minus", "fa-plus");
            }
          
          
        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
          panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          panel.style.display = "block";
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");


        var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
        if (plus.classList.contains("fa-plus")) {
            plus.classList.replace("fa-plus", "fa-minus");
        } else {
            plus.classList.replace("fa-minus", "fa-plus");
        }


        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */

.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

.active,
.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795';
    /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2796";
    /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stiles.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="faq-options">
        <button class="accordion">pregunta 1<i class="fas fa-plus" id="plus"></i></button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>prueba</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="faq-options">
        <button class="accordion">pregunta 2 <i class="fas fa-plus" id="plus"></i></button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>prueba</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="./rodri.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: La idea es que id sea único a nivel de la página, si múltiples elementos comparten id el HTML no es válido según especificación.